# Syntax for conditional statement in Wordpress functions.php

Tags: wordpress

My knowledge is extremely limited but I've managed to add a filter in a custom functions.php file to display some custom field shortcodes before Post content:

```
//Insert custom event fields at the beginning of post content
    function custom_event($content) {
    $beforecontent = '<strong>[acf field="date"] [acf field="time"] [acf field="location" ] </strong>';
    $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content;
    return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_event');
```

Can anyone please help me with the correct syntax if I want to make this conditional on the Post being in a specific category? I think I can use the in_category( 'x' ) function, I'm just not sure of the syntax. I ultimately want to add some text between the variables so it will display

> On [date] at [time] at [location]

for posts in the 'Events' category.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point.

```
function custom_event($content) {
    global $post;

    if( in_category( 'category-name-slug-id', $post ) ) {
        $beforecontent = '<strong>[acf field="date"] [acf field="time"] [acf field="location" ] </strong>';
        $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content;
        return $fullcontent;
    }

    return $content;

}

add_filter('the_content', 'custom_event');
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks Andrew. I added the text between the shortcodes and it works exactly as I wanted it!

Thanks again.

Comment: Another question if I may. I changed the $beforecontent variable to:
$beforecontent = '<strong>[ On [acf field="date"] at [acf field="time"] at [acf field="location" ]] </strong>';

How can I make the on/at/at text labels conditional so they only display if the variable is not blank, e.g., if no time or location it just outputs:
"[ On [date]]"

The shortcodes can also be called using the get_field( "acf field" ) function if it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Check if the shortcode returns an empty string or not.  You can check it's value by executing the shortcode as store the output from it using the function do_shortcode() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that looks like what I need but how would I use it for my purposes?

Comment: Read up on the function and try and code if for yourself otherwise you won't learn anything from this exercise.  I've given you the solution now it's up to you to at least make an attempt at it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrew. After much Googling and trial & error, I've come up with the following. I don't think it's a very elegant solution or even if the syntax is completely correct but it seems to work:

```
function custom_event($content) {
    global $post;
    if( get_field( "date" ) != "" || get_field( "time" ) != "" || get_field( "location" ) != "" ){ 
        $open = "&#0091;";
    }
    if( get_field( "date" ) != ""){
        $ondate = 'On '.get_field( "date" );
    }
    if( get_field( "time" ) != ""){
        $attime = 'at '.get_field( "time" );
    }
    if( get_field( "location" ) != ""){
        $atlocation = 'at '.get_field( "location" );
    }
    if( get_field( "date" ) != "" || get_field( "time" ) != "" || get_field( "location" ) != "" ){ 
        $close = "&#0093; ";
    }
    if( in_category( 'events', $post ) ) {
        $beforecontent = "<strong>$open$ondate $attime $atlocation$close</strong><br><br>";
        $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content;
        return $fullcontent;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_event');
```